# Sheet select before turning off application.screenupdating

Tags: excel, vba

I have the macro below that I want to set to have the following logic: If sheet WS_PopVsPop is not selected, then select it and then run the macro.
The issue is, right after selecting the WS_PopVsPop I have a piece of code that turns off Application.ScreenUpdating, and the sheet WS_PopVsPop contains a Pivot.
This causes a graphical error resulting in half of the new sheet to be shown, and half of the old sheet, which makes no sense.
I tried 1 x doevents, 3 x doevents, but it did not solve the problem.
What can I use to refresh the sheet so it's shown properly before running the macro?

```
Sub PopVsPop_getPopInfo_MAIN()
    If ActiveSheet.name <> WS_PopVsPop.name Then: WS_PopVsPop.Select
    ' What should i add here?
    setProgramAlertsOff
    getPOPInfo_New
    setProgramAlertsOn
End Sub

sub setProgramAlertsOff
    Applicaiton.enableevents=false
    Application.screenupdating=false
    Application.calculation=xlCalculationManual
end sub
```

Comment: Why do you have to `Select` the sheet?

Comment: To expand a bit on @Zac question, why do you need to select the sheet before you run `getPOPInfo_New`?  If your goal is to show the sheet after you've run the macro, just Select it after you've run the macro.  If there is some other reason, you'll need to provide that. It is rarely necessary to Select a Sheet/Range etc. just to run a macro.

Comment: Instead of `.Select` you could try `Thisworkbook.RefreshAll` or `activeworkbook.RefreshAll`